# Why does this calculation result in different values depending on whether arguments come from np.arange, or an int literal is used?

Tags: python, numpy, integer-overflow

Inputs:

```
f = lambda a: 6.91581104e-08 * (a**2) + (-6.00953365e-03) * a + 1.28878592e+02
{a: f(a) for a in np.arange(46000, 47000, 100)}
```

Outputs:

```
{46000: -1.2213942936000137,
 46100: -1.1854014618160136,
 46200: -1.1480254678240271,
 46300: -1.109266311624026,
 46400: -298.1009464143734,  # here
 46500: -298.05942093375745,
 46600: -298.0165122909335,
 46700: -297.9722204859015,
 46800: -297.92654551866144,
 46900: -297.8794873892135}
```

Inputs:

```
print(f(46400))
```

Outputs:

```
-1.0691239932159817
```

I tried using `def` function apart from using `lambda` function. However both give me correct values (-1ish) when printing single value. Both give me wrong values (-298ish) in iteration - I tried `for` loop, within a list, within a dict.

I assume it's about float. But not sure why it happened in iteration only, and what I should do to fix it.

Comment: It doesn't happen for me. Is it reproducible, always the same indices, the same values? What's your OS and Python version?

Comment: I can reproduce it, it seems to have to do with the values that `np.arange` generates. When using built-in `range` instead, the values are all ~ -1.0 (using Python 3.8.1 on Windows, NumPy 1.19.4

Comment: @Homer512, I get his behavior in the list comprehension on WIndows, but not on Linux.  Or the difference might be between 1.24 and 1.25

Comment: As a side note: Use [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Horner's_method) for evaluating polynomials, or [`np.polyval`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html). These would be more efficient and numerically stable than your schoolbook version

Answer (score 2):

I only get your values if I apply `f` to a whole array of `int32` dtype.  Then the `a**2` term overflows:

```
In [260]: f(np.arange(46000, 47000, 100, dtype=np.int32))
Out[260]: 
array([  -1.22139429,   -1.18540146,   -1.14802547,   -1.10926631,
       -298.10094641, -298.05942093, -298.01651229, -297.97222049,
       -297.92654552, -297.87948739])
```

I don't get the overflow when using a list comprehension.  The `a` that gets passed to `f` is now `np.int32` (I first said it was an ordinary python int.  I'm not sure why this doesn't overflow)

```
In [261]: np.array([f(a) for a in np.arange(46000, 47000, 100, dtype=np.int32)])
Out[261]: 
array([-1.22139429, -1.18540146, -1.14802547, -1.10926631, -1.06912399,
       -1.02759851, -0.98468987, -0.94039806, -0.8947231 , -0.84766497])
```

This is on an up to date python and numpy.  On my windows machine `int32` is the default.

Comparing `a**2` for the 2 dtypes:

```
In [262]: np.arange(46000, 47000, 100, dtype=np.int32)**2
Out[262]: 
array([ 2116000000,  2125210000,  2134440000,  2143690000, -2142007296,
       -2132717296, -2123407296, -2114077296, -2104727296, -2095357296],
      dtype=int32)
In [263]: np.arange(46000, 47000, 100, dtype=np.int64)**2
Out[263]: 
array([2116000000, 2125210000, 2134440000, 2143690000, 2152960000,
       2162250000, 2171560000, 2180890000, 2190240000, 2199610000])
```

Looking more at the `int32` overflow:

```
In [272]: np.array(50000,np.int32)**2
Out[272]: -1794967296
In [273]: np.int32(50000)**2
Out[273]: 2500000000
```

This is a subtle enough difference, that I wouldn't be surprised if there's been recent bug fix.

### edit

On Windows, the list comprehension produces the overflow

```
In [134]: np.array([a**2 for a in np.arange(46000,47000,100, dtype='int32')])
Out[134]: 
array([ 2116000000,  2125210000,  2134440000,  2143690000, -2142007296,
       -2132717296, -2123407296, -2114077296, -2104727296, -2095357296])

In [135]: np.int32(50000)**2   # cf [273]
Out[135]: -1794967296
```

I'm not sure if it's a linux vs windows difference, or numpy version, 1.25 vs 1.24.  I didn't see anything in the release notes suggestive of such a change.  If it's a machine difference, I'd attribute it to the c-compiler.

### again

Often when iterating it's good idea to use a list rather than array.

```
[f(a) for a  in np.arange(...).tolist()]
```

or even

```
[f[a) for a in range(...)]
```

`tolist` is faster than `list(array...)`, and produces python ints, which won't have this overflow problen.

Comment: Python ints have unlimited precision, so they never overflow.

Comment: @Barmar,  I'm trying to figure out why `np.int32` overflows in one context, but not the other.

Comment: I was answering this: "I first said it was an ordinary python int. I'm not sure why this doesn't overflow"

Answer (score 1):

It's a typing issue.

Compare:

```
f = lambda a: 6.91581104e-08*(a**2)+(-6.00953365e-03)*a+1.28878592e+02 

{a:f(a) for a in np.arange(46000, 47000, 100, dtype = int)}
```

Output:

```
{46000: -1.2213942936000137,
 46100: -1.1854014618160136,
 46200: -1.1480254678240271,
 46300: -1.109266311624026,
 46400: -298.1009464143734,
 46500: -298.05942093375745,
 46600: -298.0165122909335,
 46700: -297.9722204859015,
 46800: -297.92654551866144,
 46900: -297.8794873892135}
```

vs.

```
f = lambda a: 6.91581104e-08*(a**2)+(-6.00953365e-03)*a+1.28878592e+02 

{a:f(a) for a in np.arange(46000, 47000, 100, dtype = float)}
```

Output:

```
{46000.0: -1.2213942936000137,
 46100.0: -1.1854014618160136,
 46200.0: -1.1480254678240271,
 46300.0: -1.109266311624026,
 46400.0: -1.0691239932159817,
 46500.0: -1.027598512600008,
 46600.0: -0.9846898697760196,
 46700.0: -0.9403980647440164,
 46800.0: -0.894723097504027,
 46900.0: -0.8476649680560229}
```

You don't run into this with just `f(46500)` because you're not using a numpy data type there and python does the casting better.

Comment: It's the `a**2` that's producing an overflow when dtype in `np.int32`

Answer (score 1):

You're on Windows. NumPy's default integer dtype ([`numpy.int_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_)) corresponds to C `long`, and on Windows, C `long` is 32-bit, so `numpy.int_` is an alias for `numpy.int32`.

This default applies for both the array returned by `numpy.arange`, and for converting ordinary Python ints to values NumPy can work with in NumPy operations. When you do

```
a**2
```

`a` is a NumPy scalar of int32 dtype, and `2` is a Python int small enough to fit in the default int32 dtype, so it gets converted to int32 dtype as well.

The result gets computed in int32 dtype, and overflows.

You don't see these results with an int literal, because then the operands are both ordinary Python ints, and the result gets computed in arbitrary-precision ordinary Python int arithmetic. Other people didn't see these results on Linux, because C `long` is 64-bit on Linux, so NumPy defaults to 64-bit ints, which overflow at a higher value.

The difference other people saw on Linux between the scalar/scalar operation results and the scalar/array operation results is because [NumPy converts scalars differently in mixed scalar/array operations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html).